# How to access touch screen information from home screen on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, service, android-sensors, motionevent

I'm working on an application that continuously logs to a file touch screen information (touch x,y coordinates), I'm using a `MotionEvent` event to access that information.
I want it to continue working even if the app is closed (home button is pressed).
After some research I found a `Service` component which can perform long-running operations in the background.
The problem is the `MotionEvent` is attached to a `View` and when the app is closed it is not triggering an event anymore.

Is there another way of accessing the screen sensors? or something else I can do?
I'd really appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to continue working even if the app is closed (home button is pressed)

That is not generally possible, for privacy and security reasons. Apps cannot spy on touch input destined for other apps.

You are welcome to explore implementing an accessibility service. Please bear in mind that those APIs are designed for helping people with motor control limitations use their device and its apps. As such, using those APIs for other reasons [may not be supported by Google](https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/11/12/google-will-remove-play-store-apps-use-accessibility-services-anything-except-helping-disabled-users/).